# Filezilla client disconnects immediately after receiving hello message

Tags: ftp, filezilla, client-server

I've recently installed FileZilla server on my desktop, and a client on my laptop, both latest versions. When I try to establish a connection in my local network, everything works fine. However, trying to connect when laptop is on remote network I get this:

```
Status: Resolving address of my.ftp.server // this isn't the real address/ip of course
Status: Connecting to 24.123.185.9:5845...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response: 220 hello
Command: USER anonymous
Error: Could not connect to server
```

And the server shows this:

```
(000031)18/12/2013 23:17:12 PM - (not logged in) (31.44.131.77)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000031)18/12/2013 23:17:12 PM - (not logged in) (31.44.131.77)> 220 hello
(000031)18/12/2013 23:17:12 PM - (not logged in) (31.44.131.77)> disconnected.
```

This happens all the time.

1. I checked my server on http://ftptest.net/ and it works fine, this is why I'm assuming it's a client problem.
2. Problem occurred when firewall on both sides was turned off.
3. Tried it with anonymous user and regular password protected user

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I would have thought it is a network issue rather than a client issue - given that it works locally for you. What os and version are you running on the client?